# How to remove attributes from inherited class when parent class has it Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent class

```
class A
 has_many: B
end
```

and child class

```
class C < A
end
```

C must inherit A.

BUT

I don't want C to have an association with B
how to I can implement it?

sorry for my English.

Comment: If you child does not act like its parent, then it is not a child. Perhaps inheritance is not the answer. Consider [splitting the shared functionality into a module](https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/01/13/using-mixins-and-modules-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html) instead. We'd need more details to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Rails doesn't provide a documented method for undefining associations. While you could maybe do it by monkeying around with the association reflections (the `@_reflections` class instance variable which contains the metadata about an assocation) and  use `undef_method` to remove the generated methods it would be extremely hacky and brittle. You would be better off just listening to @Schwern's advice.